# What is the use of '_id' in ContentUris.withAppendedId

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, android-contentprovider

I have been struggling with the update of only 1 row in an SQlite databasetable.

Although I provided the _id value of the row that I wanted to update in the ContentUris.withAppendedId Uri, I still have to check in the 'WHERE'-part of the update statement whether the id of the record is the same.

When I leave the 'WHERE'-part of the update statement to 'null', the update statement tries to update ALL rows of the table instead of only the row with the id that was provided.

Answer (score 1):

URIs define a resource. They do not define what operations can be made on that resource.

With regards to a `ContentProvider` (since you've included that in the tags for your question), you need to consider that the app with the `ContentProvider` and the app that wishes to access or modify its data may not be the same app. If you are implementing a `ContentProvider`, you would need to recognize URI of the kind you mentioned and adjust the WHERE clause accordingly, assuming you support that operation on that resource.

The other use for this is with insert operations, where the typical thing to return is a URI for the item that was just inserted. E.g. a successful insert on the URI `content://authority/directory` would return something like `content://authority/directory/_id`, where _id is the ID of the newly inserted row.

Comment: OK, that's clear. But the ContentUris.withAppendedID allows access to just 1 row, being the row with the given id. So, why do I have to check it in the selection part of the update statement?

Comment: Android doesn't know what resource this URI points to, it only knows it is a resource. It doesn't know what operations you support on this resource. It doesn't know that the number at the end refers to a row ID -- it could have some other meaning. URIs can take many forms and have many path segments, so Android makes no assumptions and the responsibility lies with the developer to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: According to the ContentUris reference (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html) the id is "A unique numeric identifier for a single row in the subset of data identified by the preceding path part". In other words, it points directly to that one record that has to be updated, making an extra 'WHERE'check redundant to my opinion. If Android wouldn't know that the number at the end refers to a row ID, the 'withAppendedId' method would be complete useless.

Comment: Read the rest: "Most providers recognize content URIs that contain an id part and give them special handling. A table that contains a column named _ID often expects the id part to be a particular value for that column." And what if I don't use _ID in my table? Android knows nothing of your tables or your data -- it doesn't even know if you're *using* tables and SQLite. You could very well read the URI and use some entirely different mechanism to read/modify some data. There are no assumptions, because assumptions can be and often are wrong.

Comment: You gave me a lot to think about! :)